# How to keep all the spaces in a string?

Tags: html

When using C to write a string of html to a client socket,the length of the spaces in the string are all truncated to one when shown in a web page.How to keep all the spaces?

Comment: To do formatting in html there are tables. Also there is the "pre-formatted" markup `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: It's not a C problem and, frankly, not even a "web browser" problem. It's in the HTML specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop

Answer (score 4):

To preserve spaces in the html when shown in a web browser, use the [white-space: pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS style.

Comment: I really like your CSS solution, but I think "white-space: pre-wrap" it's better because it will wrap too long text

Answer (score 2):

Replace spaces with

> `&nbsp;`

in the output - special character for space

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` (the HTML escape sequence for a space). Whitespace is ignored by HTML interpreters, so any markup with more than 1 space next to each other will be treated as a single space.

Also, as @alk suggested, you can also surround your string with `<pre></pre>`: Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: But a space is of type char, while "&nbsp;" is of type string or char*. So it's not so easy as it seems to do the replacement.

Comment: That may be, but it is still the reason you are not seeing your mutliple spaces rendered correctly. Without seeing your code it is hard to suggest how to implement this for you.

Comment: This is almost correct, but it isn't the interpreter which collapses the whitespace. For example, you can still access the original spaces through the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see "a b" is the same as "a b" but I can see what you're trying to say. what you could do is remove all the spaces before posting and keep an array of their locations. Then use JavaScript at the other end to add back in the spaces.

More recommended is using the answer already given but I thought I would put something different out